# inherit all the fluent interfaces

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, fluent-interface

Let's say I have a class `A' with lot's of methods (which I can't grasp eventually) including a lot of fluent interfaces (including operator overloads) – returning `*this` by reference – which could become more in a later API version or so on.

I'd like to inherit all that stuff in a class `B' which has additional (fluent) methods so that all fluent interfaces of `A' (I don't want really to care about) return `*this` references as they were of type `B'.

(How) Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

After its been casted as its base type you get [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Say for object `B b` the `this` value is of type `B*`. When using its `A` member functions, `this` will be of the type `A*`.  If you cast the `A*` as an `A` object you will lose reference to all of its `B` specific data during the partial assignment.